# Using antiderivative to calculate complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

$$\int_{1}^{3}(z-2)^3 dz $$

I get the following -
$$\frac{1}{4}[(3-2)^3 - (1-2)^3] = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$$

However the answer sheet I have just show it reduced to $\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = 0$

Cant see how they are getting a - instead of a +...what am I missing?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a complex integral.  Also, the $(3-2)^3$ and $(1-2)^3$, should be $(3-2)^4$ and $(1-2)^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral of $(z-2)^3$ is $\frac14 (z-2)^4+c$ not $\frac14 (z-2)^3+c$, so you should get $$\tfrac{1}{4}(3-2)^4 - \tfrac{1}{4}(1-2)^4 =0.$$

Comment: ty, lol I even have ^4 written then when I got the antiderivative then I go and put ^3 when doing the question, im too careless.

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the power by 1 first to get:

$\frac{1}{4}[(3-2)^4 - (1-2)^4] = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = 0$